# Can't connect two attributes in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am doing some tests on sqlite for my project. But here I had some problems creating tables in the database. I want to make a connection between the number of tickets and the capacity of the plane and I would like to state that the number of tickets should be equal to the capacity of the plane, and if it is above the plane capacity, there is no room left. I am getting some errors here.

```
import sqlite3 
conn=sqlite.connect("airline.db")
cursor=conn.cursor()
sql="""Create Table TICKET(
TıcketNO Integer Prımary Key AUTOINCREMENT,
TICKETTYPE TEXT
TICKETPRICE INT,
NumberofTıckets INT)""" 


i=airline.db(TICKET(NumberofTıckets))
j=airline.db(Plane(PLANECAPACİTY))
for i in airline.db(TICKET):
    if i<j: 
       i+=1
       print("Added Successfully")
    if i>=j:
       print("There aren't enough tickets for the flight.")
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-b61114c3c1f1> in <module>
----> 1 i=airline.db(BİLET(BİLETSAYISI))
      2 j=airline.db(Uçak(UCAKKAPASİTE))
      3 for i in airline.db(BİLET):
      4     if i <j:
      5         i+=1

NameError: name 'airline' is not defined
```

How to I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code has so many problems, it doesn't really make sense to try to answer them as a single question. You can't expect to create a SQLite database in a file named `airline.db` and then expect Python to make it automatically available to you as a variable you can reference as `airline.db`, or for `TICKET` to suddenly be available. Where is `Plane` coming from? What do you expect `i` to be for each iteration?

Comment: Thanks for your interest and ı have already created plane talbe in airline.db then ı added different table by name tıcket inside same database. My request is that the system should only allow ticket sales as much as the capacity of the plane, if it exceeds this, it will give an error, how can I do this?